# What is the stable version of Weka for Windows 7 32-bit?

Tags: windows, windows-7, weka, 32-bit

I run a laptop with Windows 7 32-bit, Java 8 update 333, and Java(TM) 6 Update 7.

I used several versions of Weka, but everyone has a problem:

- version 3.9.3 and version 3.8.3: Logistic Regression classifier does not work + I face this error message "file arff not recognised as an arff file" when I try to analyze the experiment in Weka Experiment Environment. .
- version 3.6.9: I face this error message "comparison
  method violates its general contract" when I use SMOTE.

What is the stable version of Weka for Windows 7 32-bit?

Answer (score 0):

SMOTE is a third-party package for Weka and not part of the core Weka distribution. Contact the author of the [package](https://weka.sourceforge.io/packageMetaData/SMOTE/index.html) with a minimal example that exhibits that problem: version of Weka, the package, filter setup, classifier setup and dataset.